# @Html.TextBoxFor DateTime Cuts Off Time in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, google-chrome, knockout.js

My MVC 4 ViewModel has a DateTime property, and a View is rendered with the correct DateTime passed to the View (say, 3/13/2012 2:30 PM or something).

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the foo date.")]
    [DisplayName("Date:")]
    public System.DateTime fooDate { get; set; }
```

On the View, I have a @Html.TextBoxFor, which is supposed to display the DateTime:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.fooDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fooDate, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY", @data_bind = "value: fooDate" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.fooDate)
</div>
```

It only displays the Date (i.e. 3/13/2012), but I want it to display the DateTime.  I have no idea why the Time is being cut off.

**WEIRD ISSUES:**

1. Inspecting the input element, its `value` attribute is correct, and the input type is `text` (for instance, `value="8/31/2011 4:00:00 PM"`).  Trying to log the value attribute using jQuery yields `8/31/2011`, with the time cut off.
2. I'm binding the input field to Knockout.JS like this:

   ```
   fooDate: ko.observable($("#fooDate").attr("value"));
   // or
   fooDate: ko.observable($("#fooDate").val());
   ```

   Neither options yield the correct value: the time is cut off.  Using `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>` tag reveals that the observable is bound to just the Date portion of the DateTime.
3. I'm certain that the ViewModel being passed into the View contains the full DateTime value.
4. The `<input>` renders with `class="form-control hasDatepicker"`, but there's no reference in the code to this input using the jQueryUI DatePicker.

How do I debug this?  What could the issue be?

**EDIT**: <strike>The issue is only happening with Google Chrome.</strike>

**EDIT #2**:  The issue was resolved by manually clearing Google Chrome's cache (ugh), and had nothing to do with browser compatibility, HTML5, or Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual rendered `value` attribute holds the correct value and it's a text input type (rather than something like date), which you indicate is true on both counts, then the only possible explanation is some errant JavaScript is manipulating the value after it has been rendered. The fact that your input has a class, `hasDatePicker`, that you did not add manually, lends credence to this assumption. You can confirm by disabling JavaScript, and confirm that the date value is as it should be.

Now, as to how to fix this, that becomes trickier. The first step is to track down all the scripts that the page loads. This could actual script tags on your page, but it could also be dynamically loaded scripts using something like require.js, Modernizr, etc. Since this is Chrome, go to the "Resources" tab in the developer tools and expand the "Frames" folder and the folder under that representing your page. There you'll find a section for "Scripts", where you'll be able to see everything that's been included. After you find a potential offender, you'll have to work your way through your JavaScript and HTML to determine where and how it's being included.

Comment: Loose Javascript is a fair assumption, but the `hasDatepicker` class only appears in Chrome.  I've tested this in Firefox and IE11 and it's working as intended.  AFAIK, the only Javascript that is capable of manipulating this `<input>` element is Knockout.JS. Further, the input field is disabled, so I do not believe that two-way binding in Knockout.JS is to blame.

Comment: It's not knockout, either way. And just because it's only in Chrome doesn't mean that it's not JavaScript on page. There might be browser or feature-sensing involved that's only triggering in Chrome. Short of that, perhaps it's some Chrome extension you have installed. Not sure what extension would do that or why, but it is a possibility.

Comment: The issue turned out to be simply that Google Chrome needed to be refreshed (durrrrr), but I figured I'd mark Chris's answer as correct because it's good general advice to follow in this kind of situation.